# Is there a way to calculate CCDF in python?

Tags: python, graph

I had already written a code in Python to make a CDF graph.
Anyway, what I really want is a CCDF Graph.
I just know that CCDF = 1 - CDF, but i don't know how to apply it in python.

Is there anyone here know a way to calculate CCDF in Python?

Comment: Just plot `1 - x` instead of `x`? This depends entirely on what you're using to plot the CDF.

Comment: Yes, but *with what*? Python doesn't pre-install any plotting packages.

Comment: I found a value of CDF as y. Then I use this code: plot(x,1-y). Then I got this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'. What should I do, blender?

Comment: Are you using Numpy? Scipy? Matplotlib? GnuplotPy?

Comment: I am using Matplotlib and numpy

Comment: I want to post my code here, but I don't know how to post it

Comment: If you turn `y` into a Numpy array, you can plot `1 - y`. Either make it one from the very beginning, or plot `1 - np.array(y)`.

Comment: Thanks blender. Now I had posted my code in my topic...Please look at it.

Comment: I had already posted my data "test.txt".

Comment: So... what is the problem exactly? Your code is not very readable, and the question is quite vague. Are you getting error messages? Bad or unexpected results?

Comment: @hana: Plotting `plt.plot(x2, 1 - np.array(y2), ...` would be the quick fix. Making it a numpy array from the very beginning would be faster and easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blender. I did as you told me, and now I can plot 1-y. Really thanks for your help...^^

Comment: Check this example - http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/text_demo_fontdict.html

Comment: Hi @Blender. Sorry to bother you again. What should I do if I want to show the gridlines in this graph?

Answer (score 0):

Here I put a code for ploting a ccdf plot in python using having an array of x = your original values

```
colors = list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys())
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
bins = 100
cnt_color = 11
legends = []



#cdf = your_data.cumsum(0)
#ccdf = 1 - cdf
ccdf =  your_data
ax.hist(ccdf, bins=bins, density=True, histtype='step', color=colors[cnt_color], linewidth=3,cumulative=-1, label='Empirical')
legends.append('whatever')


ax.set_title('CCDF total de registros', color = mycolor)
ax.set_xlabel('#número de vendas', color = mycolor)
plt.xlim(0,50)
plt.xticks(range(0,50,5),color = mycolor)

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel('porcentagem (prob. de ocorrência)', color = mycolor)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.0,0.1), color = mycolor, fontsize=24)
plt.legend(legends)
plt.savefig('graphs_results.png')
```